# Android list images gets reloaded when scrolling up/back (using lazy loading, Picasso and android data binding)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-databinding

I have very common scenario - recycler view with items that have image and title.

I am trying to implement MVVM Pattern using Android data binding library.

I am loading images with Picasso library.

Everything works like a charm except of one thing I have problem to solve - 
images reload when I scroll back/up through my list.

For example, first time I enter the screen:

1.) I see placeholders

2.) shortly after real images are loaded

3.) scroll down - I see more placeholders (and that is fine, lazy loading)

4.) shortly after other images are loaded (great)

5.) scroll up - I see placeholders -??? the Problem - how to avoid this and instead show previously loaded images?

Here is the code (I have simplified it to just relevant parts):

ContactListAdapter.java

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Contact> items;

public Contact ListAdapter() {
    this.items = Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ContactItemBinding itemBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.contact_item,
                    parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindItems(items.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public void setList(List<Contact> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ContactItemBinding itemBinding;

    public ViewHolder(ContactItemBinding contactItemBinding) {
        super(contactItemBinding.habitItem);
        this.itemBinding = habitItemBinding;
    }

    void bindItems(Contact item) {
        if (itemBinding.getViewModel() == null) {
            itemBinding.setViewModel(
                    new ContactItemViewModel(item, itemView.getContext()));
        } else {
            itemBinding.getViewModel().setItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

}

ContactItemViewModel.java

```
public class ContactItemViewModel extends BaseObservable {

private Contact item;
private Context context;

public Contact getItem() {
    return item;
}

public ContactItemViewModel(Contact item, Context context) {
    this.item = item;
    this.context = context;
}

public void onItemClick(View view) {
    context.startActivity(ContactDetailActivity.launchDetail(view.getContext(), item));
}

public void setItem(Contact item) {
    this.item = item;
    notifyChange();
}

@BindingAdapter("android:src")
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
    Picasso.with(view.getContext())
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
            .error(R.drawable.error_image)
            .into(view);
}
```

}

contact_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.danijela.sparkle.viewmodel.ContactItemViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@{viewModel.item.imageUrl}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@{viewModel.item.fullName}" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: try to add memory and network policy in picasso code.

Comment: Did you check `Picasso.resumeTag` and `Picasso.PauseTag`? It pauses/resume picasso image loading while scrolling

Comment: Divyesh, shouldn't this be default Picasso behavior (memory + disk catche) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your code is in `onCreateViewHolder()`, it should look like this

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

and your ViewHolder constructor should look like this, in constructor you are going to bind your listItem

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    itemBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);;
}
```

refer [RecyclerView With Android DataBinding](http://www.androidgig.com/recyclerview-with-android-databinding/) for more detail

Comment: Sorry for late response,thanks,  I have tried your solution, but I have same problem as with mine. 
Have you tried your solution with more items (exceeding screen height)? 
Does it not reload when scrolling back up?